# issue with recursive function in cypress typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, cypress

I have a table that has 'add' and 'remove' buttons underneath to add and delete columns. if a column is added to the table the remove button is enabled. However, if i were to remove all the added columns the remove button would be disabled (quite understandably as there are no columns to delete).
I have written a recursive function that checks any added columns and then deletes them. The issue is it deletes all but still attempts to click the delete button. i think the issue lies in this if function-

```
if (element.find('disabled').length === 0) {
                this.deleteNonDefaultStopZones();
              }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  public deleteNonDefaultStopZones(): SettingsPage {
    cy.get('[aria-label="Remove zone price"]').then((element) => {
      if (element.find('disabled').length > 0) {
        return this;
      }
      cy.get('[aria-label="Remove zone price"]')
        .click()
        .then((element) => {
          if (element.find('disabled').length === 0) {
            this.deleteNonDefaultStopZones();
          }
        });
    });
   
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking to delete all rows, both already existing and added by your test, or are you looking to delete only the rows your test has added?

Comment: In this function I want to delete any existing rows , so that I can add them fresh later on with the aid of a diff function

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is the exit test for the recursion isn't correct.

Instead of this

```js
if (element.find('disabled').length > 0) {
  return this;
}
```

use this

```js
if (element.attr('disabled')) {
  return this;
}
```

The `.find()` method is looking for a descendent element with tag `<disabled>`, and it never finds it so the recursion never exits properly.

You might also want to add an attempts counter to block infinite recursion.

```js
public deleteNonDefaultStopZones(attempts = 0): SettingsPage {
  if (attempts > 1000) throw 'Too many attempts'
  ...
```

The upper limit of `attempts` will depend on how slow the DOM changes after `.click()` triggers column removal.

You may also want to `.wait(...)` before the next recursion

```js
cy.get('[aria-label="Remove zone price"]')
  .click()
  .wait(1000)
  .then(() => this.deleteNonDefaultStopZones())  // no need to test disabled here
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete any existing rows, you can use `.each()` to click the remove button as many times as they are rows.

```js
cy.get('.row-selector')
  .each( () => {
    cy.get('[aria-label="Remove zone price"]')
      // you may want to additional check base on how your app handles removing a row
      .should('be.visible')
      .click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot @jjhelguero and @Fody for your inputs. when @jjhelguero mentioned of rows in his comment the following funtion crept my mind. i am terribly sorry to have missed a point in my question above. by default there would be 2 columns, these cannot be deleted. any columns we add later can be deleted.

```
public deleteNonDefaultStopZones(): SettingsPage {
    cy.get('[class="MuiTableBody-root"] tr').then((element) => {
      if (element.length === 2) {
        return this;
      }
      cy.get('[aria-label="Remove zone price"]').click();
      cy.get('[class="MuiTableBody-root"] tr').then((element) => {
        if (element.length > 2) {
          this.deleteNonDefaultStopZones();
        }
      });
    });

    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Is it working with this change?

Comment: Yes it’s working fine now. 
Thanks for coming back @Fody!